# How to change JSON response on JWT Authentication for WP-API?

Tags: php, wordpress, jwt

I have used "JWT Authentication for WP-API" [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/) to login and to generate a token.

On the JSON response, I have only some data from the `wp_users` table.

How can I change it to take some others value from `wp_usermeta` table on response? I want to know user status level.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use the filters `jwt_auth_token_before_sign` or `jwt_auth_token_before_dispatch`.

The first filter receives the token data, and a user object.

In another plugin or in your theme, you'd need to call `add_filter`.

I'm a bit rusty on my WordPress, and I do not have a WP instance handy to test this out, but this is the general theory:

Basic example:

```php
add_filter('jwt_auth_token_before_sign', 'add_user_info_jwt', 10, 2);

function add_user_info_jwt($token, $user) {
      
    // fetch whatever information you want from the user, probably using the $user
    // object as starting point.

    $token['some_meta'] = $user->get('some_meta');

    return $token;
}
```

The `$token` you receive will have this starting structure and information:

```php
$token = [
            'iss'  => get_bloginfo( 'url' ),
            'iat'  => $issuedAt,
            'nbf'  => $notBefore,
            'exp'  => $expire,
            'data' => [
                'user' => [
                    'id' => $user->data->ID,
                ]
            ]
];
```

The `$user` object received by the filter is an instance of `WP_User` ([linky](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user/)).

Comment: would be great if this provided a link to the class that is `$user` so i could work out what other fields exist

Comment: Look for `WP_User`. That's the user object that this filter receives.